# xCode iOS SQLite not working update

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

Help, not working UPDATE in SQite. query is executed but the changes do not occur

```
 const char *dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK) {

    NSLog(@"database Opened");

    const char* updateQuery="update poi set test=\"111\"";

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, updateQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

        NSLog(@"Query Executed");
    }
}

sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```

Comment: You can Log errors and see what is wrong 
NSLog(@"error = %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

Comment: @Andry : Check my answer, you need to execute it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you made minor mistake....
Write ur stuff in following template, you missed the main execution statement i.e.

```
sqlite3_step(statement);
```

What is happening here, you are just preparing the statement and not executing it..

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database_object) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update table_name set column_name = \"%@\"", Your_value];
    const char *sql_stmt = [sql UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database_object , sql_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database_object));
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
        NSLog(@"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database_object));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Make these changes in your code and try, i think it will work...

Comment: You missed to write sqlite3_step statement in code. You written " Query Executed " in NSLog, so it is showing Query Executed, and u seem its working but actually u r not executing the statement..write that sqlite3_step statement, you may use template given by me, it will work........:)

Answer (score 0):

> You haven't executing the Query :

`sqlite3_prepare_v2`- Just prepared not to execute(affect) , You need to execute it

Try this Out:

```
  const char *dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK) {

    NSLog(@"database Opened");

    const char* updateQuery="update poi set test=\"111\"";

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, updateQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

        NSLog(@"Query Prepared to execute");
    }
    if(sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }else
        NSLog(@"Executed");

    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
   }
```

Comment: sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, updateQuery,
                           -1, & stmt, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"Excuted");
           
            
        } else{
            NSLog(@"Error");
          
        }